# Configure BL-C111A IP Camera

Tags: home-networking, smtp, network-camera

I am an ATT DSL customer.

I want the camera to send an email when motion detection is triggered.

Can anyone tell me how he managed to do that using:

1. GMail (I cannot because I don't think it supports SSL)
2. other alternatives if GMail is not supported

Answer (score 0):

If you have a computer on with the camera here are some options:

1. Configure that computer with a mail server.  Have the camera email your Gmail using that server as it's email server.
2. Configure that computer with [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) and have stunnel proxy the SSL part of your email connection.

Also, you could have the camera email to a non-SSL (Gmail) account and have Gmail pickup that account's email.

(Also, ensure you try both ports for Gmail 465 or 587, I have some programs that work with one and not the other.  This camera may be the same.)

I hope these tips help.

Answer (score 0):

I have my camera send me email at a gmail address, but I use my *ISP's smtp server* to do so.

At setup/trigger/motion detection

- set the transfer method to e-mail,
- set the smtp server to your friendly smtp server (I use my ISP)
- set the port to 25
- set a reply and destination email
- set a subject and any text, and then
- set up authentication as appropriate